# What is purpose of Build Class?

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build

I have used this class to get information about device manufacturer and bootloader but i do not understand what this term build means

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build

> Information about the current build, extracted from system properties.

It's information about the current Android OS build. "Build" here refers to ["Software build"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build), a compiled version of the software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. I had asked this when I was a noob to Software development, this is clear to me after spending an year in the industry learning development